# reuse list filtered in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, filter, angularjs-ng-repeat

```
<div class="info">Showing {{filtered.length}} Results</div>
<ul class="topiclist">
<li ng-repeat="product in filtered = db.products | filter:by_price_tiers | filter:by_category | orderBy:predicate">
<div>{{product.model_name}}</div>
<li></ul>
```

I can see the list changes when I apply different filters.
But filtered.length remains same all the time.
Please help me here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you've written it filtered gets all of db.products, then the filters are applied.

Try wrapping the assignment and filters in parentheses:

```
<div class="info">Showing {{filtered.length}} Results</div>
<ul class="topiclist">
<li ng-repeat="product in (filtered = db.products | filter:by_price_tiers | filter:by_category | orderBy:predicate)">
<div>{{product.model_name}}</div>
<li></ul>
```